# PsExec could not start app: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, exe, psexec

This question has been asked many times elsewhere.. but they are mostly about running things on a remote computer etc. Mine is much more straight forward.

I got an app (let's call it app.exe), which runs by a service. When it runs by the service, it is ran by the SYSTEM user.

However the app is acting weird, further when I run the same app by simply clicking on the .exe file, it runs it but with the logged in user account:

[image]

So I simply want to run *the same app* as system, that's where I found the psExec command. If I run the psExec command like so

```
c:\path\BOT>psExec "*** Bot.exe"

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
```

it works just fine, but once i put the `-s` switch (ie to run as system).. it blows up:

```
c:\path\BOT>psExec -i -s "*** Bot.exe"

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


PsExec could not start *** Bot.exe on SAMERDERNAI5012:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/979363/234141) states that if the cmd window is ran as non-admin, then it should work. I tried that but nothing happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the `bot.exe` file is not in the list of directories in the `PATH` environment variable for the SYSTEM user.

To system the system version of `PATH` open system control panel (Windows Key+Break), go to Advanced System Settings, and then Environment Variables.

Comment: ... or just provide the full path to the executable in the command line.

Comment: when I do that, i get an error window: `Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32' is denied`, although when i ran the cmd app, i right clicked and ran it as an administrator. However even when I do that, and I type `whoami` it gives me `samerdernai5012\samerdernaika` rather than system.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @abbood You have multiple issues there. Access denied: did you just pass the folder name? Re. `whoami` because that is your elevated identity not the identity used what `psexec -s` executes a command.

Comment: I copied the psTools files into `c:\windows\system32`, and it seems i don't have the rights to execute stuff from there.. so i'll add it to another folder and add that folder to the path, and make sure i got full exec rights on that and go from there

Comment: this is the command I ran: `C:\Users\samer****>psExec -i -s "C:\path\BOT\*** Bot.exe"`

Comment: So although i moved the PsExec comand to `C:\scripts` (and I verified that that's where the command is located when I run `where psExec`).. it's still giving me the `Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32' is denied`.. which is weird

Comment: update: running the command without the `-i` switch gives me this (more verbose) error:

`Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\
Windows\system32' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Bo
olean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at AIO_Bot.Form1..ctor() in C:\Users\samerdernaika\Source\Repos\aio-bot\AIOBo
t\Form1.Activation.cs:line 362..`

Comment: `..at AIO_Bot.Program.Main() in C:\Users\samerdernaika\Source\Repos\aio-bot\AIOB
ot\Program.cs:line 46
C:\AIOC\BOT\AIO Bot.exe exited on SAMERDERNAI5012 with error code 255.`

Comment: One useful – but dangerous – approach is to start an interactive session running as system: `psexec -i -s cmd.exe` and then work out the correct command line to pass to `psexec`.